# Are MapByteBuffer faster than BufferReader?

Tags: java

I am trying to extract specific data from a text file. I using bufferreader to read the file line by line so i can proccess the line.

Below are code that i written:

```
File CAD = new File (filename);

    try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(CAD)) 
    {
        String bn = CAD.getName();
        String[] bn2 = bn.split("\\.");
        BOARD_NAME= bn2[0];
        StringBuilder PACKAGE = new StringBuilder(),
        GRAPHIC = new StringBuilder(),
        PADS_DIA = new StringBuilder(),
        PADS = new StringBuilder(),
        COMPONENTS = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader))
        {
            String line;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                if (line.startsWith("J!")) 
                {
                    String[] units = line.split("!");
                    UNITS = units[8];

                } 

                else if (line.startsWith("A!REFDES!COMP_CLASS!")) 
                {

                    while (!"A!NET_NAME!REFDES!PIN_NUMBER!PIN_NAME!PIN_GROUND!PIN_POWER!".equals(line = bufferedReader.readLine())) 
                    {
                        if (line.startsWith("S!")) 
                        {
                            String[] data = line.split("!");
                            COMPONENTS.append(data[1])
                                .append("!")
                                .append(data[8])
                                .append("!")
                                .append(data[10])
                                .append("!")
                                .append(data[11])
                                .append("!")
                                .append(data[12])
                                .append("\n");


                        }
                    }


                } 

                else if (line.startsWith("A!PAD_NAME")) 
                {

                    do 
                    {   

                        if (line.startsWith("S!") && line.contains("00001")) 
                        {
                            String[] data = line.split("!");
                            if ("CIRCLE".equals(data[6])) 
                            {
                                PADS.append(data[1])
                                    .append("!C!")
                                    .append(data[7])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[8])
                                    .append("!TOP")
                                    .append("\n");

                            } 

                            else if (data[6].equals("")) 
                            {
                                PADS.append(data[1])
                                    .append("!0!")
                                    .append(data[7])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[8])
                                    .append("!TOP")
                                    .append("\n");
                            }

                            else 
                            {
                                PADS.append(data[1])
                                    .append("!R!")
                                    .append(data[7])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[8])
                                    .append("!TOP")
                                    .append("\n");
                            }
                        } 

                        else if (line.startsWith("S!") && line.contains("BOTTOM")) 
                        {
                            String[] data = line.split("!");
                            if ("CIRCLE".equals(data[6])) 
                            {
                                PADS.append(data[1])
                                    .append("!C!")
                                    .append(data[7])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[8])
                                    .append("!BOTTOM")
                                    .append("\n");
                            } 

                            else if (data[6].equals("")) 
                            {
                                PADS.append(data[1])
                                    .append("!0!")
                                    .append(data[7])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[8])
                                    .append("!BOTTOM")
                                    .append("\n");
                            }    

                            else 
                            {
                                PADS.append(data[1])
                                    .append("!R!")
                                    .append(data[7])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[8])
                                    .append("!BOTTOM")
                                    .append("\n");
                            }


                        } 

                        else if (line.startsWith("S!") && line.contains("~DRILL")) 
                        {

                            String[] data = line.split("!");
                            PADS_DIA.append(data[1])
                                .append("!")
                                .append(data[6])
                                .append("\n");

                        }

                    }while (!"A!GRAPHIC_DATA_NAME!GRAPHIC_DATA_NUMBER!RECORD_TAG!GRAPHIC_DATA_1!GRAPHIC_DATA_2!GRAPHIC_DATA_3!GRAPHIC_DATA_4!GRAPHIC_DATA_5!GRAPHIC_DATA_6!GRAPHIC_DATA_7!GRAPHIC_DATA_8!GRAPHIC_DATA_9!SUBCLASS!SYM_NAME!REFDES!".equals(line = bufferedReader.readLine()));           
                } 

                if (line.startsWith("A!SYM_NAME!"))                
                {
                    int k =0,j=0;
                    String[] data1 = line.split("!");
                    for (int i =0; i<data1.length;i++)
                    {
                        if (data1[i].equals("PIN_NUMBER"))
                        {
                            k=i;
                        }
                        else if (data1[i].equals("PIN_ROTATION"))
                        {
                            j=i;
                        }
                    }
                    while(!"A!VIA_X!VIA_Y!PAD_STACK_NAME!NET_NAME!TEST_POINT!".equals(line = bufferedReader.readLine()))
                    {  
                        if (line.startsWith("S!")) 
                        {
                            String[] data = line.split("!");
                            if (data[8].equals("")||data[8]==null)
                            {}
                            else
                            {
                                PACKAGE.append(data[1])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[k])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[k+1])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[k+2])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[k+3])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[k+4])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append(data[j])
                                    .append("\n");                      
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }

                else if (line.startsWith("A!CLASS!SUBCLASS!GRAPHIC_DATA_NAME!"))
                {          

                    while (!"A!SUBCLASS!PAD_SHAPE_NAME!GRAPHIC_DATA_NAME!GRAPHIC_DATA_NUMBER!RECORD_TAG!GRAPHIC_DATA_1!GRAPHIC_DATA_2!GRAPHIC_DATA_3!GRAPHIC_DATA_4!GRAPHIC_DATA_5!GRAPHIC_DATA_6!GRAPHIC_DATA_7!GRAPHIC_DATA_8!GRAPHIC_DATA_9!PAD_STACK_NAME!REFDES!PIN_NUMBER!".equals(line = bufferedReader.readLine()))
                    {
                        if (line.startsWith("S!BOARD GEOMETRY!OUTLINE")) 
                        {
                            //to find the diamension x and y of board
                            String data[]=line.split("!");
                            double valuex = Double.parseDouble(data[6]);
                            double valuey = Double.parseDouble(data[7]);
                            PANEL_X.add(valuex);
                            PANEL_Y.add(valuey);

                        }

                        else if (line.startsWith("S!REF DES"))
                        {
                            String data[] = line.split("!");
                            if (data[2].equals("ASSEMBLY_TOP")||data[2].equals("DISPLAY_TOP"))
                            {
                                GRAPHIC.append(data[12])
                                    .append("!")
                                    .append("TOP")
                                    .append("\n");
                            }

                            else if(data[2].equals("ASSEMBLY_BOTTOM")||data[2].equals("DISPLAY_BOTTOM"))
                            {
                                GRAPHIC.append(data[12])
                                   .append("!")
                                   .append("BOTTOM")
                                   .append("\n"); 
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    double max_x = max(PANEL_X);
                    double min_x = min(PANEL_X);
                    double max_y = max(PANEL_Y);
                    double min_y = min(PANEL_Y);
                    double diamensionx = max_x - min_x;
                    double diamensiony = max_y - min_y;
                    MIN_X = min_x;
                    MIN_Y = min_y;
                    BOARD_X = diamensionx;
                    BOARD_Y = diamensiony;
                    BOARD_Z = 62.9921;

                }

                ArrayList<String> $TEMP_LIST = new ArrayList<>(asList(GRAPHIC.toString().split("\n")));
                HashSet<String> graphic = new HashSet<>($TEMP_LIST);
                GRAPHIC_LIST = new ArrayList<>(graphic);
                PACKAGE_LIST = new ArrayList<>(asList(PACKAGE.toString().split("\n")));
                PADS_LIST = new ArrayList<>(asList(PADS.toString().split("\n")));
                PADS_DIA_LIST = new ArrayList<>(asList(PADS_DIA.toString().split("\n")));
                COMPONENTS_LIST = new ArrayList<>(asList(COMPONENTS.toString().split("\n")));           
            }

        }                
        fileReader.close();
        }
```

On my code,still got many `if else` condition. When i try to extract from a file size about 20MB , it take time like 30 seconds. But when i try to read a file size about 200MB , it take very long time, like more than 30 minutes.My friends suggest me to use `MappedByteBuffer` to proccess faster.

I am still new in Java. So do `MappedBuffer` perform faster than `BufferReader` in this case? If yes , how can i process the data line by line?

Comment: You can read millions of lines a second with `BufferedReader`. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: ya.. i knew that..so i wondering is it too much `if else` condition make BufferReader perform badly.

Comment: That question doesn't begin to make sense. The performance of the `BufferedReader` has nothing whatsoever to do with the if-else's, and whatever other reading technology you use, you will still have the if-else's, unless you find a way to improve them, in which case `BufferedReader` would benefit just as much as any other technology. And `MappedByteBuffer` doesn't support reading lines.

Comment: One thing you could do is to read the file into a string buffer first before you being to manipulate the content. Also look at what you are doing with the content and areas where you can improve. If you deem the buffered reader is giving an issue, then check the Java NIO 2 package which does Native file reads as opposed to going through the JVM.

Comment: @dinukadev Pre-reading the file would only add more latency and waste memory.

Comment: @EJP well the code already uses multiple string buffers, I believe having the file read into one buffer and manipulating it afterwards is one option to consider. It is an internal buffer and the memory will be released after execution and you can have a soft reference to it if need be.

Comment: @dinukadev One option to consider ***why?*** Given that it will waste both time and space? And what do soft references have to do with anything?

Comment: @EJP i think we are going off topic here. So i will leave it here. Let us agree to disagree.

Comment: @dinukadev I agree. You always were off topic.

Comment: @EJP very professional of you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your issue is with `BufferedReader`, it's fast enough for almost all purposes. Using `MappedByteBuffer` does allow you to read the contents (or parts of it) of a file into memory all at once, but then you're dealing with a `ByteBuffer` instead of lines of text, and it's unlikely that you'd get a significant performance improvement with it.

If you remove the contents of the while loop and just read the lines without any processing, you'll notice that a file of 20MB is read in an instant.

An obvious (minor) improvement is to move the `line.split("!")` into the scope where it's actually needed. I'm not sure if the code you're showing is your actual code (probably not since you spelled `split()` as `splits()`, but in the example code you would only need to split the line if it starts with `cga`. Without seeing your actual code it's hard to point out all the locations that make it slow (you could use a profiler of course).

As a last suggestion, if you're writing Java professionally, you might want to avoid non-Java things like `$` in variable names, and opening braces on their own lines (Java adheres to [1TBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_1TBS)). It's helpful to other Java developers who may read your code.

Comment: i have put my code inside the question. Are there any thing make the proccess time slow? 30 secs still acceptable but i dont't know why it would take more than 30 min to proccess a larger file.

Comment: Well, it's not very readable. The first thing I would do is refactor the code so that most of the if clauses would become of the form `if(something) { output.addAll(mySomeMethodProcessing(input)); }`. That way you'll get the `if` logic clearer and you can give the methods a descriptive name (at the moment your code is pretty much unreadable). Joop Eggen's suggestion about setting the initial capacity is a good idea too, so the `StringBuilders` and `ArrayLists` don't need to perform unnecessary growing.

Answer (score 1):

Without profiling this is difficult to answer correctly.
One thing which might be worth trying:

You use `String.split` for each line. For every call of `split`, Java compiles a Pattern:

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
}
```

So it may be better to compile the Pattern you use only once at the beginning:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("!");
Pattern patternNL = Pattern.compile("\n");
```

and use this to split your strings:

```
String[] parts  = pattern.split(line);
String[] singleLines = patternNL.split(lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily faster; only if your text file becomes in the order of 100 MB, you might consider such a thing.

**Better do other optimizations first.**

Like `new StringBuilder(10_000)`. Also for BufferedReader.